# HPA Keep the oldest pod when scaling down

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

When the HPA scales up it creates new pods, when it scales down those new pods are terminated and HPA keeps the oldest ones. Can I configure something to say to HPA to terminate the oldest pods and keep some newest?

Comment: All the pods being identical, why would you wanna do that? Please elaborate your use case?

Comment: Following [this scheduler issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4301) will likely interest you, and [this one](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45509) which sounds much closer to your actual problem. Good luck!

Comment: I have a pod that has a  woker written in kotlin. This worker has some coroutines to consume msgs from an sqs queue and after some time (between 24-40 hours) these coroutines stops to consume the sqs queue. The hpa is scaling up based on the quantity of msgs that I have in the queue and because of the pods stops of consuming the queue the hpa starts to scale.. the newest pods are working well while the oldest are not processing the messages, so I've trying to found a way remove this oldest pods when scale down (even though it's a partial solution while we do not find the real reason)

Comment: Does comment of @mdaniel clarify your doubts ?

Comment: Yes, I figure out how to resolve. Thank you guys

Comment: Can you post your answer ?

Comment: I didn't use the HPA, I create a monitor of kotlin coroutines into my code and when the kubertes make the health check it checks the status of my coroutines, when the coroutine is not active hpa restarts the pod

Comment: Can you post it as an answer not in comment section ?

Answer (score 1):

As @ianprogrammer mentioned

> create a monitor of Kotlin coroutines into code and when the
> Kubernetes make the health check it checks the status of my
> coroutines. When the coroutine is not active
> [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)  restarts the pod.

Also as @mdaniel adviced you may follow [this issue of scheduler](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4301).

See also similar problem: [scaling-deployment-kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45509).